# Binary search in R

Tags: beginner, r, binary-search

Again playing around in `R` with a [Edx CS50 homework](http://cdn.cs50.net/2016/x/psets/3/pset3/pset3.html#searching).

Performance relative to `%in%` is above my expectation. But I still wonder whether I am breaking any good practice/style, norms, or common sense overall or in the tiniest detail.

```
BiSearch <- function(table, key) {
  # Takes sorted (in ascending order) vectors
  stopifnot(is.vector(table), is.numeric(table))
  r <- length(table)
  m <- ceiling(r / 2L) # Midpoint
  if (table[m] > key) {
    if (r == 1L) {
      return(FALSE)
    }
    BiSearch(table[1L:(m - 1L)], key)
  }
  else if (table[m] < key) {
    if (r == 1L) {
      return(FALSE)
    }
    BiSearch(table[(m + 1L):r], key)
  }
  else {
    return(TRUE) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see the (presumably `C`) code behind the `match()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's point out that `%in%` and `match` do not require that the input be sorted so they should asymptotically (i.e as the input becomes large) perform way worse than your code if implemented properly.

My main concern with your implementation would be that you are disregarding potential floating point errors. See for example that

```
BiSearch(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.1), 0.3)
# [1] FALSE
```

To fix that, you need to allow for some very small tolerance. You could mimic `all.equal` by setting that tolerance to `.Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5`:

```
BiSearch <- function(table, key, tol = .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5) {
   ...
   if (table[m] > key + tol) { ... }
   else if (table[m] < key - tol) { ... }
   ...
}
```

Next, from a performance point of view, you are wasting a good amount of time and memory by creating and storing a new vector at each iteration. Instead, you could keep the same initial vector and only pass around start and end indices:

```
BiSearch2 <- function(table, key, start.idx = 1, end.idx = length(table),
                      tol = .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5) {
   # Takes sorted (in ascending order) vectors
   stopifnot(is.vector(table), is.numeric(table))
   r <- length(table)
   m <- as.integer(ceiling((end.idx + start.idx) / 2)) # Midpoint
   if (table[m] > key + tol) {
      if (start.idx == end.idx) return(FALSE)
      Recall(table, key, start.idx = start.idx, end.idx = m - 1L, tol = tol)
   } else if (table[m] < key - tol) {
      if (start.idx == end.idx) return(FALSE)
      Recall(table, key, start.idx = m + 1L, end.idx = end.idx, tol = tol)
   } else return(TRUE)
}
```

Notice how I also made a few other changes:

1. `ceiling` returns a numeric so it needs to be passed through `as.integer` if you want to preserve an integer class for your index
2. I used `Recall` rather than the name of the function itself. This is preferred as it makes it easier to later rename your function: you will only have to change the function name in one place instead of three.
3. Though this has no negative effect within the body of a function, I used the preferred bracing syntax where `else` is put on the same line as the previous `}`. Outside functions, especially when writing code at the terminal, this would otherwise throw an `unexpected else` error. This is well explained  in section 8.1.43 of the R inferno: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

At this point, the code should be a lot faster. So fast that the repetitive checking via `stopifnot` becomes relatively expensive so it makes sense to turn it off within the nested calls:

```
BiSearch3 <- function(table, key, start.idx = 1, end.idx = length(table),
                      tol = .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5,
                      check = TRUE) {
   # Takes sorted (in ascending order) vectors
   if (check) stopifnot(is.vector(table), is.numeric(table))
   r <- length(table)
   m <- as.integer(ceiling((end.idx + start.idx) / 2)) # Midpoint
   if (table[m] > key + tol) {
      if (start.idx == end.idx) return(FALSE)
      Recall(table, key, start.idx = start.idx, end.idx = m - 1L, tol = tol, check = FALSE)
   } else if (table[m] < key - tol) {
      if (start.idx == end.idx) return(FALSE)
      Recall(table, key, start.idx = m + 1L, end.idx = end.idx, tol = tol, check = FALSE)
   } else return(TRUE)
}
```

Here are some benchmark comparisons using a large input vector:

```
library(microbenchmark)
table <- 1:1e7
microbenchmark(BiSearch(table, 1L), BiSearch2(table, 1L), BiSearch3(table, 1L))

# Unit: microseconds
#                  expr        min          lq        mean      median         uq        max neval
#   BiSearch(table, 1L) 146830.845 166891.1690 221590.9946 253923.2490 276508.785 290987.343   100
#  BiSearch2(table, 1L)    342.497    352.9960    376.3591    370.3830    377.602    561.851   100
#  BiSearch3(table, 1L)    119.976    124.0535    136.2610    130.1285    143.567    298.806   100
```

I leave that up to you but at this point, I think you would probably get even faster computation times if you replaced the recursion by a simple `while` loop (since time is lost calling the function many times and maintaining a stack of function calls).